# PIL cannot open multi-image tiff

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, tiff

I've got [this](https://isic-archive.com/api/v1/image/5436e3abbae478396759f0cf/download?contentDisposition=inline) multi-image tiff and when I try to open it with PIL like so

```py
from PIL import Image
Image.open(image_path)
```

I receive the following exception:

`OSError: cannot identify image file 'image.tiff'`

However I am able to split the tiff into multiple valid single-image tiffs using ImageMagick via the following command on ubuntu 16.04:
`convert image.tiff img_split-%d.tiff`.
This means that the file is valid.

#### Question

Why can't I open the file using PIL?
And if it is impossible to use PIL in this situation, what other library can I use to interact with the images in the file?

Comment: `ISIC_0000000.tiff` is a BigTIFF (not TIFF) file, which is not supported by Pillow.

Comment: That's wonderful to know the exact format! :) I'll look into ways to interact with it. Can you tell me how you found out the exact format of the file?

Comment: Not only is it a 64-bit TIFF, it is also JPEG compressed (which is rare itself) rather than LZW so it is going to be even harder to find a library  read it.

Comment: Maybe just use **ImageMagick** to convert it to a TIFF that PIL can read, e.g. `convert yours.tif -compress lzw new.tif`

Comment: The program should also work on windows therefore I guess I cannot rely on ImageMagick :\

Comment: I've found *libtiff* which can handle the file :)

Comment: ImageMagick is available for Windows, Linux and macOS - all work well. If you install v7 for Windows, the command will become `magick yours.tif -compress lzw new%d.tif`

Comment: [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) can handle those files but the imagecodecs library (required to decode JPEG compressed tiles) will not compile out-of-the box on older Ubuntu or macOS.

Comment: I've found tifffile as well, but I could not get imagecodecs installed (ends with an error, tried to search a solution for it).

Comment: You should be able to do that with Python Wand, which makes calls to ImageMagick, which in turn calls libtiff. The latter needs to be installed, but is supported on Window, Mac OSX and Linux